# Firefox Google search language is set to Spanish

Tags: firefox, language, google-search

Whenever I search Google from Firefox it takes me to search results in a strange language with "buscar" instead of "search" etc.

```
google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-9609672093949948%3A2pdkvfm6u5y&ie=ISO-8859-
```

Any idea how to get it back to English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the page (http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en) there you can change the settings for the search results. If that does not work, try clearing your cookies.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) , i fixed it by removing the search engine and re-adding from http://mycroftproject.com/google-search-plugins.html